# Is there any solution for my code in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to render all of the pdfs' first page as images and pass them to Home Screen. I make Splash Screen's duration to 30second. But I think it is not right because there can be hundreds of pdfs in someone's phone storage and Splash Screen's duration can be longer than 30seconds. So is there any solution to my problem?  Here is my code. Enlighten me pls.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:native_pdf_renderer/native_pdf_renderer.dart';
import 'package:splash_screen_view/SplashScreenView.dart';
import 'constant.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';
class Splashscreens extends StatefulWidget {
  _SplashscreensState createState() => _SplashscreensState();
}
class _SplashscreensState extends State<Splashscreens> {
    List<FileSystemEntity>? filepdf;
    List<Uint8List>? imagepdf = [];
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getFile();
   }
   getFile() async {
      await Permission.storage.request();
      final myDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/documents/');
      filepdf = myDir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: true);
      for (int index = 0; index < filepdf!.length; index++) {
      final document = await PdfDocument.openFile(filepdf![index].path);
      final page = await document.getPage(1);
      final pageImage = await page.render(width: page.width, height: page.height);
      setState(() {
          imagepdf!.add(pageImage!.bytes);
       });
      }
     }
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SplashScreenView(
           navigateRoute: HomeScreen(filepdf, imagepdf),
           duration: 25000,
           imageSize: 650,
           imageSrc: "assets/image/jensenpdfviewerlogo.jpg",
           colors: [
             Colors.purple,
             Colors.blue,
             Colors.yellow,
             Colors.red,
             Colors.orange,
             Color(0xFFECECEC)
              ],
           pageRouteTransition: PageRouteTransition.SlideTransition,
           text: "LOADING......",
           textType: TextType.ColorizeAnimationText,
           textStyle: fontStyle,
           backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4E4AC2),
           ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: you can use FutureBuilder to know if state is loading or loaded and in Loading state you can show SplashScreen

Comment: I did use Future Builder but nothing happened. I don't know why. Maybe my code was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

```dart
class Splashscreens extends StatefulWidget {
  _SplashscreensState createState() => _SplashscreensState();
}
class _SplashscreensState extends State<Splashscreens> {
  
  List<FileSystemEntity>? filepdf;
  List<Uint8List>? imagepdf = [];

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getFile() async {
    await Permission.storage.request();
    final myDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/documents/');
    filepdf = myDir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: true);
    for (int index = 0; index < filepdf!.length; index++) {
      final document = await PdfDocument.openFile(filepdf![index].path);
      final page = await document.getPage(1);
      final pageImage = await page.render(width: page.width, height: page.height);
      setState(() {
        imagepdf!.add(pageImage!.bytes);
      });
    }
    var data = {
      "file_pdf": filepdf,
      "image_pdf": imagepdf
    };

    return data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getFile(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); 
          case ConnectionState.done:
            Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!;
            List<FileSystemEntity>? _filePdf = data["file_pdf"];
            List<Uint8List>? _imagepdf = data["image_pdf"];
            return YourResultScreen();  
          default: 
            return Container(); 
        }
      }
    );  
  }

}
```

Comment: What about 'filepdf'. I also need filepdf to pass as a argument like "case ConnectionState.done: HomeScreen(filepdf,snapshot.data)"

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check the above method getFile() and on case ConnectionState.done

Comment: I don't know what was wrong. Still can't access files and images with future builder.